# android - Replacing fragment in the middle of retrofit calls cause fragment transaction to produce awkward result

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have a problem. in my android app, I have a fragment that performs retrofit call. Inside the fragment, there is a button to navigate to the next fragment. If I click the button after the retrofit call is finished, there is no problem. However, the problem emerges when I click the button when the call is executing. The fragment is replaced but not completely. As you can see in the images I uploaded, the button stayed on top of the replaced fragment.

[image: Initial state of the fragment]

The retrofit call is invoked by performing swipe to refresh on the screen and if in the middle of doing that I changed to another fragment, the result can be seen below (In this case I clicked the button at the bottom)

[image: Awkward result of fragment transaction]

While the expected result should be like this. **(Also note that although the awkward result shows that the previous fragment is on top of the fragment replacing it, the UI widgets of the previous fragment is not responsive while the one beneath it is clickable.**

[image: Expected]

The xml for the first fragment (showing list of attendances)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/refresh_attendance"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/attendance_list"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:name="proj.com.fyp.AttendanceFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context="proj.com.fyp.AttendanceFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_attendance" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_appeal_attendance"
            android:text="@string/appeal_attendance"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

```java
@OnClick(R.id.button_appeal_attendance)
public void showAppealFragment() {
    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(null);
}
```

The method that does the api call (also in AttendanceFragment.java)

```java
private void loadData() {
    mRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
    Log.i(TAG, "loadData: ");
    RequestInterface request = RestHelper.getClient();
    request.getOverallAttendancesRx("TP035763")
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeWith(disposableObserver);
}
```

the `disposableObserver` is defined like so:

```java
    disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<List<ModuleOverallAttendance>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<ModuleOverallAttendance> value) {
            try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){
                Log.i(TAG, "onNext: " + (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()));
                Log.i(TAG, "onNext: ");
                realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
                    r.insertOrUpdate(value);
                });
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onNext: ", e);
                onError(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            mRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: " + (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()));
            try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){
                mRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                moduleOverallAttendances = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(ModuleOverallAttendance.class).findAll());
                mAdapter.setmValues(moduleOverallAttendances);
                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: a");
                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: ", e);
            }
        }
    };
```

The actual fragment transaction is handled in the MainActivity.java

```java
@Override
public void onListFragmentInteraction(ModuleOverallAttendance item) {
    Log.i("onFragmentInteraction", "DummyItem: " + item);
    if (item.getModuleId() == null) {
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, AppealAttendanceFragment.newInstance(),"AppealAttendance")
                .commit();
        setTitle("Appeal Attendance");
        toggleHamburger(false);
    } else {
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, AttendanceDetailsFragment.newInstance("", ""),"AttendanceDetails")
                .commit();
        setTitle(item.getModuleId());
        toggleHamburger(false);
    }
}
```

I cancel the request in the onDestroy method

```java
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroyView: ");
    mRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
    unbinder.unbind();
    disposableObserver.dispose();
    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: share some code please

Comment: @KlitosG. Added the code, feel free to request more if necessary.

Comment: Is your "faulty" case the successful if inside the onListFragmentInteraction method?
why in your first transaction you remove the existing Fragment and then add another one? Use replace instead of add and delete the remove line.
I think you cannot have both remove(...) and add(...) inside a Transaction. If I am right, then only add is working and you see both Fragments one on top of the other

Comment: It is the successful if inside the onListFragmentInteraction method. I just changed it to `replace`, but the same result happens.

Comment: updated code and images @KlitosG.

Comment: can't see something bad at the moment.
If you have not resolved it I might be able to try run your code in the weekend.

How do you load your initial fragment? Generally just make sure that you use "replace" instead of "add" on all your transactions. Even if it is the first one

Comment: Hey @KlitosG. , the root of the issue is apparently SwipeRefreshLayout which has already been an issue for a while [Issue #78062](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78062). The workaround I found from that link that works is to call `mRefresh.removeAllViews()` in `onDestroyView`. Thank you for trying to solve the issue.

Comment: No worries. Glad you found the issue.
Create a valid answer yourself and accept it when you are allowed so that the question is not unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the SwipeRefreshLayout. From this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78062) there are some workarounds that can be used solved the issue. In my case, calling `mRefresh.removeAllViews` in `onDestroyView()` does the job.